# Wireless Connection unstable with multiple devices connected

Tags: wireless-networking, router, connection

My wireless network works perfectly when only 1 device is connected. Super fast, full strength. But as soon as multiple devices are connected to the wireless network the connections become unstable (constantly losing connection with the internet, not the network itself). It's quite annoying.

I have a Sitecom Wireless 300N XR Gigabit Router WL-306, which should be a decent router so I'm guessing there must be something wrong with my configuration.

Does any of you know what might cause this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by disabling the "Enable Auto Channel Scan option" under Basic // Wireless xGhz.